# Password generator class

Tags: strings, security, random, swift

I've written this class to generate a random password and was wondering if there's anything I could improve upon here and whether or not this a safe (most random) method of generating a password.

There's only one function in here which can be used to create an alphanumerical password of a specified length. It can also be overloaded to be more specific in which characters it will use.

The code works as it's supposed to.

```
import UIKit

class codeGen: NSObject {

    private let base: String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    private let lowerChars: String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    private let numberChars: String = "1234567890"
    private let specialChars: String = "!@#$%^&*"

    func generate(length: Int) -> String
    {
        let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let len = UInt32(letters.length)

        var result = ""

        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
            var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
            result += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
        }

        return result
    }

    func generate(length: Int, lowers: Bool, numbers: Bool, specials: Bool) -> String
    {
        var letters = base

        if (lowers == true)
        {
            letters += lowerChars
        }
        if (numbers == true)
        {
            letters += numberChars
        }
        if (specials == true)
        {
            letters += specialChars
        }

        let NSletters : NSString = letters as NSString
        let len = UInt32(NSletters.length)

        var result = ""

        for _ in 0 ..< length {
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
            var nextChar = NSletters.character(at: Int(rand))
            result += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
        }

        return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type names in Swift use UpperCamelCase (compare [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)), so it should 
be `class CodeGen`.

I do not see any reason why the class must inherit from `NSObject`.
Actually the methods do not use any state. If the sole purpose of
the class declaration is to provide a namespace (and to avoid free
global function) then you use an `enum` with type methods instead:

```
enum CodeGen {

     static func generate(length: Int) -> String { ... }

}
```

so that you can call them as

```
let password = CodeGen.generate(length: 16)
```

instead of creating an instance:

```
let password = CodeGen().generate(length: 16)
```

The advantage of usage an `enum` over a `struct` is that you can not
(inadvertently)  create an instance of the type 
(compare https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#constants,
or [Swift constants: Struct or Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum)).

The explicit type annotations in

```
private let base: String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
// ...
```

are not necessary, that can be simplified to

```
private let base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
// ...
```

You have two functions implemented independently:

```
func generate(length: Int) -> String 

func generate(length: Int, lowers: Bool, numbers: Bool, specials: Bool) -> String
```

but actually the first function is a special case of the second.
Therefore the first method can simply forward to the second:

```
func generate(length: Int) -> String {
    return generate(length: length, lowers: true, numbers: false, specials: false)
}
```

Alternatively, implement only a *single* method with default
parameter values:

```
func generate(length: Int, lowers: Bool = true, numbers: Bool = false, specials: Bool = false) -> String
```

Testing a boolean value `if (lowers == true)` can always be
simplified to `if (lowers)`, and the parentheses are not needed:

```
if lowers {
    letters += lowerChars
}
```

The type annotation in

```
let NSletters : NSString = letters as NSString
```

is again unnecessary, and variable names should start with a lowercase
letter. But the bridging to `NSString` can be avoided completely by creating a Swift `Array` of `Character`:

```
let characters = Array(letters.characters)
let numChars = UInt32(characters.count)
var result = ""
for _ in 0 ..< length {
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(numChars))
    let nextChar = characters[rand]
    result.append(nextChar)
}
```

which can be simplified to

```
let characters = Array(letters.characters)
let numChars = UInt32(characters.count)
let result = String((0..<length).map { _ in
    characters[Int(arc4random_uniform(numChars))]
})
```

The argument names can be improved, perhaps `useLowercase` or
`withLowercase` instead of `lowers` etc.

Putting it all together the code would look like this:

```
enum CodeGen {

    private static let base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    private static let lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    private static let numberChars = "1234567890"
    private static let specialChars = "!@#$%^&*"

    static func generatePassword(length: Int, useLowercase: Bool = true,
                                 useNumbers: Bool = false,
                                 useSpecialChars: Bool = false) -> String {
        var letters = base
        if useLowercase {
            letters += lowerChars
        }
        if useNumbers {
            letters += numberChars
        }
        if useSpecialChars {
            letters += specialChars
        }

        let characters = Array(letters.characters)
        let numChars = UInt32(characters.count)
        let result = String((0..<length).map { _ in
            characters[Int(arc4random_uniform(numChars))]
        })

        return result
    }

}
```

The static variables can also be moved into the method unless
you need to share them with other methods of the `CodeGen` type.

Comment: Note that if you're going for pure namespace, an `enum` is preferable to a `struct` – although that being said, I would consider making the different options (`length`, `useLowercase`, etc.) instance properties of `CodeGen` (there's probably a better name for that type too), so the caller doesn't have to keep track of the values itself (allowing it, for example, to easily change one of the options between repeated invocations). You'd still be able to call `generate` in one line – it would just be `CodeGen(length: 16).generate()` instead.

Comment: @Hamish: Good suggestion about enum. – I am not sure about the other suggestion. It perhaps depends on what else the `CodeGen` class is used for.

Comment: You're right that it does depend on exactly how OP's using it currently, but I do think for increased flexibility (especially with code re-use) that it's a good change to make, as it both maintains the ability to use it as a single-call generator, and enables the ability to re-use a given set of generating options for a given generating instance. I went ahead and [posted an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/163900/104723) with the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Following directly on from the [excellent suggestions by @MartinR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/163888/104723), I would firstly rename `CodeGen` to `PasswordGenerator` – which is a much clearer name for 
it. It also fits better with the [API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), which discourages the use of abbreviations ("Gen" instead of "Generator"):

> - **Avoid abbreviations.** Abbreviations, especially non-standard ones, are
>     effectively terms-of-art, because understanding depends on correctly
>     translating them into their non-abbreviated forms.
>
>   The intended meaning for any abbreviation you use should be easily
>     found by a web search.

Then, I would consider making the different password generating options actual instance properties of `PasswordGenerator` (therefore we need to make it a `struct`, as enumerations cannot contain stored properties).

This increases the flexibility of the API, as it allows for easy re-use of a particular password generating instance. It could even, for example, serve as a model for a view controller (e.g you could have a `passwordGenerator` property with a `didSet` observer that updates the UI with a new randomly generated password upon the options being changed, with various UI elements being able to change those options).

So we now have:

```
struct PasswordGenerator {

    private static let base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    private static let lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    private static let numberChars = "1234567890"
    private static let specialChars = "!@#$%^&*"

    var length: Int
    var useLowercase: Bool
    var useNumbers: Bool
    var useSpecialChars: Bool

    init(length: Int, useLowercase: Bool = true,
         useNumbers: Bool = false,
         useSpecialChars: Bool = false) {

        self.length = length
        self.useLowercase = useLowercase
        self.useNumbers = useNumbers
        self.useSpecialChars = useSpecialChars
    }

    func generate() -> String {

        var letters = PasswordGenerator.base

        if useLowercase {
            letters += PasswordGenerator.lowerChars
        }
        if useNumbers {
            letters += PasswordGenerator.numberChars
        }
        if useSpecialChars {
            letters += PasswordGenerator.specialChars
        }

        let characters = Array(letters.characters)
        let numChars = UInt32(characters.count)

        let result = String((0..<length).map { _ in
            characters[Int(arc4random_uniform(numChars))]
        })

        return result
    }
}
```

I've also renamed the `generatePassword()` method to `generate()`, as it's now clear from the type name what the method is generating.

However, those `Bool` properties to control the characters used aren't particularly elegant – I would recommend encapsulating them in a `CharacterSet` nested type, which we can then conform to [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset), allowing us to easily combine multiple character sets together:

```
extension PasswordGenerator {

    struct CharacterSet : OptionSet {

        static let lowercase = CharacterSet(rawValue: 1 << 0)
        static let uppercase = CharacterSet(rawValue: 1 << 1)
        static let numbers   = CharacterSet(rawValue: 1 << 2)
        static let symbols   = CharacterSet(rawValue: 1 << 3)

        static let letters: CharacterSet = [.lowercase, .uppercase]
        static let alphanumeric: CharacterSet = [.letters, .numbers]

        let rawValue: Int

        var characters: Set<Character> {

            var characters = Set<Character>()

            if contains(.lowercase) { // in Swift 4, remove ".characters"
                characters.formUnion("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)
            }

            if contains(.uppercase) {
                characters.formUnion("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)
            }

            if contains(.numbers) {
                characters.formUnion("1234567890".characters)
            }

            if contains(.symbols) {
                characters.formUnion("!@#$%^&*".characters)
            }
            return characters
        }
    }
}
```

*(Note that this will conflict with `Foundation`'s `CharacterSet`, but given as it's a nested type, this shouldn't be problematic, as it will only conflict in the scope of `PasswordGenerator`)*

This also lets us define some custom character sets, such as `letters` and `alphanumeric`, which are a combination of other sets – as well as encapsulate the logic to produce the set of characters to work with, as this could well be re-used.

Note that we're now using a `Set` to represent the collection of characters we can choose from, as it better describes the collection (unique characters that aren't ordered) – not to mention allowing for constant lookup time of a given character in the set.

Now we just have to refactor `PasswordGenerator` to use our nested `CharacterSet` type instead of the `Bool` properties:

```
struct PasswordGenerator {

    var length: Int

    var characterSet: CharacterSet {
        didSet {
            // re-compute the characters array after the character set changing.
            characters = Array(characterSet.characters)
        }
    }

    private var characters: [Character] // cached characters.

    // default options of just using letters (upper and lowercase)
    init(length: Int, characterSet: CharacterSet = .letters) {
        self.length = length
        self.characterSet = characterSet
        self.characters = Array(characterSet.characters)
    }

    /// Generate a new password with a given length from the given character set.
    ///
    /// - Precondition: The character set must be non-empty.
    func generate() -> String {

        precondition(!characters.isEmpty,
                     "Cannot generate password from an empty character set.")

        let characterCount = UInt32(characters.count)

        let result = (0 ..< length).map { _ in
            characters[Int(arc4random_uniform(characterCount))]
        }

        return String(result)
    }
}
```

You can see we're now also:

- Caching the characters to generate the password from (re-creating upon the character set changing, with a `didSet` observer)
- Using our custom `.letters` option as the default character set to generate from.
- Guarding against an empty character option set being selected by using a `precondition` check.

We can now simply use it like so:

```
var passwordGenerator = PasswordGenerator(length: 16, characterSet: .alphanumeric)
print(passwordGenerator.generate()) // GcWrH81pYU46m4lx

passwordGenerator.length = 20
print(passwordGenerator.generate()) // 9SNiPlgYqRCpvpP96cuT

passwordGenerator.characterSet.subtract(.lowercase)
print(passwordGenerator.generate()) // YX1WELZEC7GN4L2JTAVR
```

I have included the full code [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/08f898c746dcc25e6d11e7401dc1c4a2) for your convenience.

Comment: Another option would be to make `characters.isEmpty` a `fatalError()`. Tacitly using an empty password string might have unwanted consequences.

Comment: @MartinR That's a good point – I did consider it, but at the time thought the caller should be handling whether they want to allow an empty character set or not. Although, upon rethinking, I can't actually think of a useful scenario where the caller would want an empty string – so I agree erroring out is the better option.

Comment: Thanks to both you and @MartinR for your suggestions! I'll include these in my code and study up on the things that are new to me.